# Regex to Match Domain Name

Tags: python, regex

```
^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}$
```

I tried the code above but it would not match any domain no matter how ugly.

I am try to match only domain with words and ending in .com

```
Like 
google.com
yahoo.com
bing.com

Not 
google.net
google.con
googl-e.com
```

Comment: `e.com` is only words and ends with `.com`. Shouldn't that be included?

Comment: The regex matches all of the 6 examples. So what do you mean by "it would not match any domain"?

Comment: Please post more of your code.  Are you using the `re` module?  If so, what function are you using to find the domain names?

Comment: I trying to match domain without numbers and dashes. Like google.com and not like goo-gle.com or googl2.com.

Comment: Rawing code only matches the first line

Comment: (([A-Z]+\.)(COM)) this seems to work but how do i get it to ignore domains with - slashes -

Comment: FYI, domain names can contain dashed

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of the `-[a-z0-9]+` group? I got your six test cases to pass with:

```
import re
r = re.compile("^([a-z0-9]+\.)com$")

# Like
assert r.match('google.com')
assert r.match('yahoo.com')
assert r.match('bing.com')

# Not 
assert not r.match('google.net')
assert not r.match('google.con')
assert not r.match('googl-e.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not match any because it uses the `^` and `$`which matches the start and end of string.  To make it match the start and end of a line, you have to enable the multiline option `re.M`.  In addition, use `re.I` to make it case insensitive which I believe domain names are.

#### Based on your requirements:

1. Ends with `.com`
2. No dashes
3. No numbers

**Code**:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^[a-z]+\.com$' , re.M | re.I)

print(regex.findall("""\
google.com
yahoo.com
bing.com
google.net
google.con
googl-e.com
"""))

# => ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'bing.com']
```

**To break it down:**

```
^        # To mark the start of line/string
[a-z]+   # One or more alphabet
\.       # match the `.` character
com      # match the `com` string
```

Answer (score -1):

I often have problems with the $ in the end, so I'd add \s* after the ^ and before the $ operators, to detect leading/trailing separator-characters. Can't reason too much without knowing the context.

```
^\s*([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}\s*$
```

Comment: this will match any TLD. OP wants .com only.